# How to calculate Heating/Cooling Degree Day using some API in python

Tags: python-3.x, web-services, weather-api

I am trying to calculate heating/cooling degree day using (T<sub>base</sub> - T<sub>a</sub>) formula **T<sub>base</sub>** is usually 65F and **T<sub>a</sub>** = (high_temp + low_temp)/2

(example)

```
high_temp = 96.5F low_temp=65.21F then 
mean=(high_temp + low_temp)/2
result = mean - 65
```

65 is average room temperature
if result is > 65 then cooling degree day (cdd) else heating degree day (hdd)

I get weather data from two API:

- weatherbit
- darksky

In **weatherbit** the provide both cdd and hdd data, but in **darksky** we need to calculate using above formula (T<sub>base</sub> - T<sub>a</sub>)

My problem is both API show different result (example)
darksky JSON response for day:

```
{
"latitude": 47.552758,
"longitude": -122.150589,
"timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
"daily": {
    "data": [
          {
            "time": 1560927600,
            "summary": "Light rain in the morning and overnight.",
            "icon": "rain",
            "sunriseTime": 1560946325,
            "sunsetTime": 1561003835,
            "moonPhase": 0.59,
            "precipIntensity": 0.0057,
            "precipIntensityMax": 0.0506,
            "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1561010400,
            "precipProbability": 0.62,
            "precipType": "rain",
            "temperatureHigh": 62.44,
            "temperatureHighTime": 1560981600,
            "temperatureLow": 48,
            "temperatureLowTime": 1561028400,
            "apparentTemperatureHigh": 62.44,
            "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1560981600,
            "apparentTemperatureLow": 46.48,
            "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1561028400,
            "dewPoint": 46.61,
            "humidity": 0.75,
            "pressure": 1021.81,
            "windSpeed": 5.05,
            "windGust": 8.36,
            "windGustTime": 1560988800,
            "windBearing": 149,
            "cloudCover": 0.95,
            "uvIndex": 4,
            "uvIndexTime": 1560978000,
            "visibility": 4.147,
            "ozone": 380.8,
            "temperatureMin": 49.42,
            "temperatureMinTime": 1561010400,
            "temperatureMax": 62.44,
            "temperatureMaxTime": 1560981600,
            "apparentTemperatureMin": 47.5,
            "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1561014000,
            "apparentTemperatureMax": 62.44,
            "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1560981600
           }
        ]
    },
    "offset": -7
}
```

python calculation

```
response = result.get("daily").get("data")[0]
low_temp = response.get("temperatureMin")
hi_temp = response.get("temperatureMax")
mean = (hi_temp + low_temp)/2
#65 is normal room temp
print(65-mean)
```

Here mean is  6.509999999999998
65 - mean = 58.49
**hdd is 58.49** so **cdd is 0**

Same date in weatherbit JSON response is:

```
{
 "threshold_units": "F",
 "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
 "threshold_value": 65,
 "state_code": "WA",
 "country_code": "US",
 "city_name": "Newcastle",
 "data": [
   {
     "rh": 68,
     "wind_spd": 5.6,
     "timestamp_utc": null,
     "t_ghi": 8568.9,
     "max_wind_spd": 11.4,
     "cdd": 0.4,
     "dewpt": 46.9,
     "snow": 0,
     "hdd": 6.7,
     "timestamp_local": null,
     "precip": 0.154,
     "t_dni": 11290.6,
     "temp_wetbulb": 53.1,
     "t_dhi": 1413.9,
     "date": "2019-06-20",
     "temp": 58.6,
     "sun_hours": 7.6,
     "clouds": 58,
     "wind_dir": 186
   }
 ],
 "end_date": "2019-06-21",
 "station_id": "727934-94248",
 "count": 1,
 "start_date": "2019-06-20",
 "city_id": 5804676
}
```

here **hdd is 6.7** and **cdd is 0.4**

Can you explain how they get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use hourly data to calculate the HDD and CDD, and then average them to get the daily value.

More details here: https://www.weatherbit.io/blog/post/heating-and-cooling-degree-days-weather-api-release

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake calculating mean temp for the first station
and 
the second station is miscalculating CDD and HDD.
You cannot have a positive HDD and CDD so I have no idea how they got those values.

The `mean` of the `first station` is `55.93F`, `HDD is 9.07`, and `CDD is 0`
Daily Mean calculation;

```
(62.44 + 49.42)/2 = 55.93F
```

HDD calculation;

```
65 - 55.93 = 9.07
```

The `HDD` of the `second station` is `6.4` and `CDD is 0`.
HDD calculation;

```
65 - 58.6 = 6.4
```